# Autofilling some field in all AD accounts

Tags: active-directory, automation, user-accounts

Is there a way to auto-fill a field or set of fields for all AD accounts in one go?

For example if I want to set address field for all employees or in a specific OU? Or perhaps if I need to set their email field to username@companydomain.com

Comment: If you're scripting the modification (e.g. with Powershell) you may do whatever you like.  If you're not a scripting person, there are also tools like [ADModify.NET](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996216(v=exchg.65).aspx) which do bulk edits. Could you provide some detail about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @jscott, in fact its for preferable easy to do bulk edits. ADModify seems like a perfect tool. I will give it a try

Comment: @jscott if you promote it to answer I will mark it up and green ;)

Comment: Fair enough, done sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give [ADModify.NET](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996216(v=exchg.65).aspx) a try. It is a GUI based tool for performing bulk AD edits.  The tool also offers AD attribute variable expansion and it generates "undo" files for all changes.  It is quite handy if scripting is unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in 3rd party tools, have a look at http://www.adaxes.com.
[image: Property Patterns]

[Automatically Set Users' Address Based on Their Office](http://www.adaxes.com/tutorials_SimplifyingDataEntry_AutomaticallySetUserAddressBasedOnOffice.htm)